# Symfony 3 factory repository

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, phpunit, config

Create a container in service.php

```
$container->setDefinition('repository.access_token', 
        new Definition(\Ftob\OauthServerApp\Repositories\AccessTokenRepository::class))
    ->setFactory([new Reference('doctrine'), 'getRepository'])
    ->setArguments([\Ftob\OauthServerApp\Entity\AccessToken::class]);
```

I try to call it in the test -

```
class AccessTokenRepositoryTest extends KernelTestCase
{

protected $repository;

public function setUp()
{
    $this->bootKernel();
    $this->repository = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('repository.access_token');
}

public function testDi()
{

    $this->assertInstanceOf( AccessTokenRepository::class, $this->repository);
}

}
```

I receive an error (fail) -

> AccessTokenRepositoryTest::testDi
>   Failed asserting that Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository Object (...) is an instance of class "Ftob\OauthServerApp\Repositories\AccessTokenRepository".
>
> /var/www/tests/Repositories/AccessTokenRepositoryTest.php:23
>
> FAILURES!
>
> Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.

Why call instance Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository, not AccessTokenRepository?

Thanks!

Comment: Does Doctrine know, that you are using custom repository? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes